# terminal closes when I run shell script

Tags: command-line, scripts

I wrote my own shell script, and I made it executable with `chmod +x` command. But when I click to shell file and want to run it in terminal, it suddenly opens and then closes in a second. What is the problem?

Comment: When scrpits have errors they exit. So unless you list the contents of the script its a guessing game

Comment: no, script hasn't any error. I just want to simply run it in Terminal with clicking to the current file.

Comment: Also, it's not true that scripts always exit when they have errors. Scripts such as `rc.local`, which are run with `sh -e`, will do (essentially) this. But most scripts don't run that way. Of course many scripts are deliberately written to exit under a variety of specific error conditions, but the author of the script would know about this if they had deliberately written their script that way.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It also closes automatically once it has run your command.
Add `/bin/bash` at the end of your script to keep the terminal open.

You can also add a `&& sleep 10` to keep the terminal open 10 seconds and see what's going on.

Alternatively, add another line containing `read` at the end of the script to keep the terminal open until you press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: or add the sleep 10 to the exit point (end?) of the script.

Answer (score 8):

I have faced a similar situation.
I was executing my script as

```
. helper.sh
```

Instead try executing it as

```
./helper.sh
```

This worked for me.

Comment: FYI: `. script.sh` means the same as `source script.sh`

Comment: This "answer" is correct, but mostly for the scenario when `exit` is executed.

Answer (score 2):

Try commenting out all your "exit" commands (if any) in your script by placing # in front of them and give it a go. Perhaps you are executing "exit" in your shell that closes the terminal session.